# Import css files in client app created in dotnet core angular-5 application on VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, angular5, primeng

I have started a new **.Net Core + Angular 5** application using VS2017's create project wizard.

I want to use primeng component library in this project.

It has some css files inside its `node_modules/primeng/` folder, which I need to import in my angular app for better UI.

I tried following code as shown there website but it is not working:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />
```

In my another app made on VSCode I used following code to add these files in **.angular-cli.json**:

```
   "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css"
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
      ],
```

But in this project made on VS2017 I am not able to find any sutable location to inject these files.

Answer (score 0):

In your `webpack.config.vendor.js` file you have to add the module you want to bundle as `vendor`. if you install `primeng` and `primeicons` as `npm` dependencies you can use the following code. Put then in the `nonTreeShakableModules` so it doesn't get strip when you `publish` you app.

```
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'es6-promise',
    'es6-shim',
    'event-source-polyfill',
    'primeicons/primeicons.css',
    'primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css',
    'primeng/resources/primeng.min.css'
];
```

You may have to modify also some `rules` to include images of `primeicons`. In the same file add `gif` to the `test` node

```
module: {
     rules: [
             { test: /\.(png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
            ]
        },
```

Then make sure you include the `vendor.css` file in your template/layout and you should be good to go!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/vendor.css" asp-append-version="true">
```

To re-bundle the vendor files you may have to delete the `dist` folders in `wwwroot` and `Clientapp` and just rebuild your project

Comment: Please keep in mind, that there is no `webpack.config.vendor.js` when using an out-of-the-box angular-cli (the new asp.net core angular templates use angular cli rather than webpack directly) unless you run eject on the project, which will unfold the webpack files. But once done, all the ease of using cli is gone and there's "no way back" and from there people have to manage their webpack themselve

Comment: @tseng Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately when I try to generate the Web Application Angular from VS I get the following configuration with the `webpack.config.vendor.js`. I will try to update my VS and all components and retry to see if the configuration changes.